# Add one dimension for a 2D distance map in Paraview

Tags: data-visualization, paraview

I use Paraview to visualize a 2D distance map. 
Below what I obtain where geodesics are represented with different colors. 
I use the VTK file format RECTILINEAR_GRID.

[image]

I would like to add a dimension z where the height would depend on the scalar field value u without having to rewrite an other file.
Example can be found [here](http://roboticslab.uc3m.es/albums/fmarching/slowness.png).

Comment: You can use the Warp by Scalar filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lib comment, [Warp by Scalar filter](http://www.vis.lbl.gov/NERSC/Software/paraview/docs/HTML/paraview.htm#filters_warp.htm) indeed answers my question.
It is available in the menu Filter->Alphabetical->Warp by Scalar.
Just leaving the default values gave me what I need.